# Value createGlobalTempView is not a member of apache.org.spark.sql.DataFrame

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to register the DataFrame as a global temporary view using below statement in Spark with Scala:

```
df.createGlobalTempView("people")
```

It is not not recognizing the `createGlobalTempView` on `DataFrame` object.

It's showing the error:

> value createGlobalTempView is not a member of
>   org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame.

Am I missing any library imports?

Answer (score 1):

`createGlobalTempView` is not present in the current stable version (Spark 2.0). It have been added in 2.1.0 which is not released yet.

Answer (score 0):

[Global Temporary View](https://people.apache.org/~pwendell/spark-nightly/spark-master-docs/latest/sql-programming-guide.html#global-temporary-view)

Temporary views in Spark SQL are `session-scoped` and will disappear if the session that creates it terminates.

If you want to have a temporary view that is shared among all sessions and keep alive until the Spark application terminates, you can create a **global temporary view**. Global temporary view is tied to a system preserved database global_temp, and we must use the qualified name to refer it, e.g. SELECT * FROM global_temp.view1.

```
// Register the DataFrame as a global temporary view
df.createGlobalTempView("people")

// Global temporary view is tied to a system preserved database `global_temp`
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM global_temp.people").show()
// +----+-------+
// | age|   name|
// +----+-------+
// |null|Michael|
// |  30|   Andy|
// |  19| Justin|
// +----+-------+

// Global temporary view is cross-session
spark.newSession().sql("SELECT * FROM global_temp.people").show()
// +----+-------+
// | age|   name|
// +----+-------+
// |null|Michael|
// |  30|   Andy|
// |  19| Justin|
// +----+-------+
```

> Global Temporary View is not part of Spark 2.0.2 (latest) version.
>
> Global Temporary View is part of next [release](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/v2.1.0-rc1/examples/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/examples/sql/SparkSQLExample.scala#L141)